# Sharepoint & infopath dropdown list options based on columns

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, sharepoint-designer, infopath2010

I have a database with 6 columns (stages), under these columns are lists of options. I want to have a drop down list which contains the options based on the "stage" selected from a dropdown box just before (they are all in the same DB).

So the user selects a stage, and the next box has a drop down of the options relevant to that stage. I can't figure it out through filters or rules and their isn't a lot online about it, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: So two dropdowns? One with a list of the six stages, the other to show the values of the selected stage?

In the second dropdown, just pull in all values, and add a filter so it only shows the values for the stage selected in the first dropdown.